# How does twitter give me a callback for tweeting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, callback

The Tweet Button is usually:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="someone">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

and here I can get a callback when the user tweets:

```
<script>
  twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  });
</script>
```

What I don't understand: how does twitter give me this callback? The tweet is done in another window and from another domain. How is this possible?

Comment: iframe, http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: Did you try looking at the JS source to see  it you could find where they do the magic?

Comment: yeah. didn't find anything. obviously obfuscated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather this is Twitters own implementation of [Web Intents](http://webintents.org/) which is a Web API loosely based on Androids Intents functionality.  It looks like that Twitter are using a JavaScript implementation of Web Intents [(possibly similar to this](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/webintents)).

In this scenario, the Twitter JavaScript registers an `intent` with the browser. The `intent` being you sharing a URL. When the user clicks the tweet button the `intent` activity is started and a new pop-up windows is displayed.

The user clicks the tweet button from the pop-up window and the browser posts back the event data to a callback specified when starting the activity. The callback is specified in the `widget.js` and you hook up to this event using the `twttr.events.bind` method.

There is a really good example of how this works on the [JavaScript github](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/webintents) implementation of WebIntents.

> **Usage**
>
> **To use today**
>
> No browsers currently support this API natively. To use this system
>   simple drop the following code in to your site:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://webintents.org/webintents.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> When browsers start to implement this natively the Shim will defer all
>   its functionality to the native interface.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> To register your service application to be able to handle image
>   sharing simply declare an intent tag.
>
> ```
> <intent 
>   action="http://webintents.org/share"
>   type="image/*" />
> ```
>
> This will register the current page's ability to share images.
>
> **Invocation**
>
> To build a client application that can use the share functionality, it
>   is as simple as using the following code:
>
> ```
> var intent = new Intent(
>     "http://webintents.org/share", 
>     "image/*", 
>     "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Three_jolly_kittens.png/800px-Three_jolly_kittens.png"
>
> );
> window.navigator.startActivity(intent);
> ```
>
> **Service**
>
> When a service is invoked via startActivity, the "intent" object on
>   window will be populated with the data provided by the client.
>
> ```
> window.intent
> ```
>
> That's it.
>
> To send data back to the client that invoked it, it is as simple as
>   calling postResult() on the intent.
>
> ```
> window.intent.postResult("something cool");
> ```

The example is obviously slightly different to the Twitter implementation but the general process is the same.

Here are few other references for the WebIntents API:

- [Chromium Project - Web Intents](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/webintentsapi)
- [Another Example of how WebIntents is used from the Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/08/connecting-web-apps-with-web-intents.html)
- [Twitter Web Intents API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)

Answer (score 1):

Windows opened via JavaScript (e.g, `window.open`) get a reference to the window that created them in `window.opener`, which they can use to "talk back" to the parent.

Comment: Could you provide an example? How do they do this **cross domain**?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure what your doing here but cross domain javascript api's are accomplished with jsonp: <strike>Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.</strike>
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Edit 1: 
JSONP is an approach to access cross domain services.  A simple approach to this problem is to use round robin polling. Unfortunately polling does not scale when you have many clients.  Keeping a persistent connection through tcp sockets and having the server **PUSH** new messages to the subscribed clients is a better alternative to classic polling.

While i haven't used WebSockets that is how the server can push back to the client data if it's not implementing round robin.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

Comment: JSONP and CORS are exact opposites.

Comment: @eli grey - We currently use jsonp to allow users to host a survey javascript pluggin that hits our rackspace servers (not the origin).  Quote:"pattern of usage allowing a page to request data from a server in a different domain. JSONP is a solution to this problem"   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing   JSONP and CORS are not "exact opposites".

Comment: CORS is requesting any data (such as JSON) from other origins using Access-Control headers. JSONP is JavaScript, not JSON, that is run on your site, giving the other origin full control of your site.